# Afraid to restart nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

## Background

I have a problem with the nginx server I inherited.  First, I have several nginx versions installed and I have reason to believe that if I just reboot, a *different* version of nginx would end up getting run on startup than what I have running right now. Yikes!

I got a huge leg-up from the answer to my previous question: [I have multiple instances of nginx, but not sure which one is "correct"](https://serverfault.com/questions/832609/i-have-multiple-instances-of-nginx-but-not-sure-which-one-is-correct)

## Questions

1. Is it preferred to use `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` to restart nginx instead of calling a `nginx` executable directly myself?
2. based on the contents of `/etc/init.d/nginx` and the output of `ps aux | grep nginx` (see appendix below), am I correct in assuming that a reboot of the server or just invoking `nginx -s reload` would cause a different version of `nginx` to run?
3. I believe I can rectify the mismatch between what's running and what's configured in `init.d` by changing line 22 of `/etc/init.d/nginx` from `nginx="/usr/sbin/nginx"` to `nginx="/usr/local/nginx-nobrotli/sbin/nginx"`... is that correct? That would leave me with using the `/usr/local/nginx-nobrotli/sbin/nginx` which I believe is what I am running now and I definitely prefer to keep the server running as-is for now.

## Appendix

Contents of `/etc/init.d/nginx`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemon
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15
# description:  Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse \
#               proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
# processname: nginx
# config:      /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# config:      /etc/sysconfig/nginx
# pidfile:     /var/run/nginx.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/usr/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

sysconfig="/etc/sysconfig/$prog"
lockfile="/var/lock/subsys/nginx"
pidfile="/var/run/${prog}.pid"

NGINX_CONF_FILE="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

[ -f $sysconfig ] && . $sysconfig


start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc -p $pidfile $prog
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest_q || return 6
    stop
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest_q || return 6
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc -p $pidfile $prog -HUP
    echo
}

configtest() {
    $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

configtest_q() {
    $nginx -t -q -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# Upgrade the binary with no downtime.
upgrade() {
    local oldbin_pidfile="${pidfile}.oldbin"

    configtest_q || return 6
    echo -n $"Upgrading $prog: "
    killproc -p $pidfile $prog -USR2
    retval=$?
    sleep 1
    if [[ -f ${oldbin_pidfile} && -f ${pidfile} ]];  then
        killproc -p $oldbin_pidfile $prog -QUIT
        success $"$prog online upgrade"
        echo 
        return 0
    else
        failure $"$prog online upgrade"
        echo
        return 1
    fi
}

# Tell nginx to reopen logs
reopen_logs() {
    configtest_q || return 6
    echo -n $"Reopening $prog logs: "
    killproc -p $pidfile $prog -USR1
    retval=$?
    echo
    return $retval
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest|reopen_logs)
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload|upgrade) 
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        upgrade
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    status|status_q)
        rh_$1
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|reload|configtest|status|force-reload|upgrade|restart|reopen_logs}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Output of `ps aux | grep nginx`:

```
nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx-nobrotli/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Can you clone / virtualise this server and experiment on a test box? Messing around in production isn't a good idea. 1) Yes.  2) Not enough information to say 3) Yes, most likely

Comment: This script says it operates on `/usr/sbin/nginx`. So it's probably not what was being used. If it were me, I would build a new server from scratch and migrate the web site to it. There's way too much _wrong_ on this one.

Comment: I advised you what to do  the last time you asked this. The comments above say exactly the same as I previously said. Do that and win.

Comment: @is the English way: from your response to my comment on the other one, it sounded like you wanted to be done with this question so I elected to create a new question for the follow up questions I had. The course of action you provided sounds great, but I wanted to ask a couple of specific "nits" that you didn't cover.  I even linked to the original question to make it clear these follow-up questions were separate.

Comment: @Tim: thank you for your answer 1, 2, and 3.  I just needed a little validation in that area before proceeding.